# How do I set a public variable inside typescript function?

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to set a public variable inside another function. I couldn't make it through.

```
export class MyClass{
    myVar = false;

    myFunction(){
        Module.anotherFunction(){
            this.myVar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

how do I make myVar to true from inside another function calling `this.myFunction()`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  You can't define a new function inside `myFunction` the way you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the method syntax to assign a function to another object, you can do this:

```
export class MyClass{
    myVar = false;

    myFunction(){
        Module.anotherFunction = () => {
            this.myVar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of an arrow-function, this will bind `this` to `MyClass`.